# 32 bit ODBC Driver to connect to a 64 bit Database

Tags: c++, sql-server, oracle, db2, odbc

In order to connect to a 64 bit Database (Oracle / DB2 / Postgresql/ SQL Server) from a 32 bit  Software via ODBC, do I need the 32 bit Database client or just the 32 bit ODBC Driver would suffice.

As an example from Oracle, when I am installing Oracle Server, the 32 bit ODBC Administrator, does not necessarily have an entry for Oracle as the 32 bit ODBC Driver does not exist. In order to connect, I had to install the 32 bit Oracle Client, after which I can see an ODBC entry.

So my question is, in order to connect to a 64 bit database from a 32 bit application, do I need the 32 bit database client (thin/full) or just there exist a 32 bit ODBC driver which can be installed to establish a connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which client you use is dependent on the architecture of the client machine you are using, not the server.

IIRC, with Oracle you need to install the client AND the ODBC driver. The client actually handles the connection to the database while the ODBC layer translates ODBC-speak to something the client understands.

I assume other platforms are similar although it is possible some databases supply an unified client installer that can install both the client and the ODBC driver.

When using ODBC, it is important to use the ODBC architecture that matches your client application. For example, If you are using x86 Access you would need the 32 bit ODBC driver and client.

Comment: Though I got the essence of your answer but I may have to disagree with your statement `is dependent on the architecture of the client machine`. As an example a 32 bit client can be installed on a 64 bit box. Also, if you can more details to your answer (like references) it would be worth while.

Comment: @Abhijit you are correct but the original question was if the architecture of the server determined which client should be installed. Once you start talking about ODBC, the right answer is likely more dependent on  the application using ODBC.

Comment: I think the gist of the OPs question `in order to connect to a 64 bit database from a 32 bit application, do I need the 32 bit database client (thin/full) or just there exist a 32 bit ODBC driver which can be installed to establish a connection.`

Comment: The answer is correct. As long as the appropriate release of driver is available in 32 and 64 bit, then your best bet is usually to match the mode of the client, which is where you are running the driver.  But make sure your driver supports the version of your server's software. For example, don't try to use a driver for DB2 LUW 9.1 if you are connecting to a server running DB2 LUW 10.1

Answer (score 0):

When I setup a SQL Linked Server to Oracle, I installed:

- Net Configuration Assistant
- Net Manager
- ODBC Driver
- OLE Driver

The driver architecture should match the machine architecture.  In my case it was 64bit Windows Server, so I used the 64-bit driver (win64_11gR2_client.zip).

I then ran the Net Config. Assistant and setup the oracle config (host/port/user/pass/service name).  Make sure you pass a connection test here.  This will configure your tnsnames.ora file (%path%\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora)

If you can't connect, look into the sqlnet.ora file.  I had to alter mine to read  `SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE)` before I could connect successfully.

I then ran ODBC to setup a System DSN using the same name setup in the Net Config. Assistant.

Comment: `In my case it was 64bit Windows Server, so I used the 64-bit driver`, so you are saying a 32 bit driver cannot be installed on a 64 bit machine? I thought, ODBC drivers not being a kernel drivers, do not have the restrictions.

Comment: I think you can, they'll just show in the 32-bit odbc panel instead of the primary odbc panel on a 64-bit machine.  I feel your pain on this, setting up oracle took me hours, and numerous installs/uninstalls, I tried 32-bit and 64-bit.  If you do wind up uninstalling, there is an oracle provided uninstaller -- highly recommend the download -- don't just use the add/remove icon in control panel -- it leaves stuff everywhere.

Comment: fyi uninstaller is win64_11gR2_deinstall.zip, its on the oracle site.

Answer (score 0):

Following is valid for Oracle, I don't know if it all applies also for other RDBMS.

Database server and client are independent from each other, i.e. you can connect with an 32-bit Oracle Client to a 64-bit Oracle database server.

However the architecture of ODBC-Driver and Oracle Client have to match, i.e. a 32-bit ODBC driver works only with an 32-bit Oracle Client, a 64-bit ODBC driver needs the 64-bit Oracle Client. This restriction applies also for other providers like OLE DB or ODP.

A 64-bit Oracle client requires a 64-bit Windows, of course. Installing a 32-bit Oracle client on 64-bit Windows is no problem.

It is also possible to have both 32-bit and 64-bit Oracle client (and thus both architectures of ODBC drivers) installed on the same machine. However, you have to do a few "tricks" to make them both working seamless.